# SQL Server Xquery, cast to decimal with localization it-IT

Tags: sql-server, localization, xquery, xquery-sql

I have a list of decimal values in XML formatted with italian localization (that is comma as decimal separator and dot as thousands separator) and I have to convert to decimal values.

The XML is like this:

```
<ROW>
  <COSTO>2</COSTO>
  <COSTO>3,6</COSTO>
  <COSTO>1.005,10</COSTO>
</ROW>
```

When are extracted, the decimal numbers will be:

```
2
3.6
1005.10
```

I'm using `REPLACE` function to remove dots and convert commas to dots, before useing `CONVERT` function:

```
CONVERT(decimal(10,2), REPLACE(REPLACE(
  XMLDATA.value('(//COSTO)[1]','nvarchar(20)')
  , '.',''), ',','.'))
```

Is there any syntax to make Xquery read the value using localization, to get the value as decimal?

Something like this (this is not working):

```
XMLDATA.value('(//COSTO)[1] with local it-IT','decimal(10,2)')
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 0):

If there are commas in the value, you can convert to MONEY first， For example:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml='<ROW>
          <COSTO>2</COSTO>
          <COSTO>3,6</COSTO>
          <COSTO>1.005,10</COSTO>
</ROW>' 
SELECT  CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(t.v)=1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(10,2),REPLACE(REPLACE(t.v,'.',''),',','.') ) ELSE 0 END    
FROM @xml.nodes('ROW/COSTO') s(b)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(s.b.value('.','varchar(100)'))) t(v)
```

```
---------------------------------------
2.00
3.60
1005.10
```

If your server version is up 2012, you can use PASE function

```
 SELECT  PARSE(t.v AS MONEY USING 'it-IT')
 FROM @xml.nodes('ROW/COSTO') s(b)
 CROSS APPLY(VALUES(s.b.value('.','varchar(100)'))) t(v)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The final values should be: 2 , 3.5  and 1005.1.

Comment: you can use  CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(t.v)=1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(10,2),REPLACE(REPLACE(t.v,'.',''),',','.') ) ELSE 0 END

Comment: I'm already use two `REPLACE`, I want to extract the value with localization to avoid the use of these two `REPLACE`.